# Inner Join tables replacing ID values

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

I have a table of teams each with an ID number like this...

```
TEAM ID      TEAM
1            Maitland
2            Orlando
3            Winter Park
4            Lake Mary
```

So on and so forth

And I have a table that lists out the schedule using only the ID numbers like so...

```
TEAM ID      Game1     Game2    Game3
1            2         3        4
```

Is it possible to INNER JOIN those top to tables to create a table that replaces the ID numbers with the correct team name like this...

```
TEAM        Game1      Game2         Game3
Maitland    Orlando    Winter Park   Lake Mary
```

Comment: Yes, you have to join to your teams table once for each game.  So 3 Joins back to teams table form teh schedule table.  Or you can restructure the data so that the matches list 2 teams and a separate fields lists the game, then you would have to pivot the game data.  Will your MATCHES table only always have 3 games?

Comment: No, each team will have 10 games.

Comment: Given this design you may be better off simply creating a procedure that does a lookup for each name. that way you stick with a simple join and simply call the procedure for each team and game.

Comment: What if there's a 4th game? Your schema is broken

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.name as TEAM_ID, t2.name as Game1, t3.name as Game2, t4.name as Game3
from schedule s
     inner join teams t1 on t1.team_id = s.team_id
     inner join teams t2 on t2.team_id = s.Game1
     inner join teams t3 on t3.team_id = s.Game2
     inner join teams t4 on t4.team_id = s.Game3
     ...
     ...
     inner join teams t10 on t10.team_id = s.Game9;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a 1:n team-game relationship.

If you just store it in normal form - teamid, game - ordered in some way, like, by date:

```
CREATE TABLE schedules (
    teamid INT,
    playing_with INT,
    order DATE

    FOREIGN KEY (teamid)
       REFERENCES teams(teamid)        
);
```

then you'll have it all in two joins:

```
SELECT t.teamname AS team, t1.teamname AS PlayWithTeam
FROM schedules s
    INNER JOIN teams t ON s.teamid=t.teamid
    INNER JOIN teams t1 ON s.playing_with=t1.teamid
ORDER BY s.teamid, s.order;
```

[Here's the Fiddle, check it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e95f3/1).